# How can I programmatically scroll UIScrollView from start to end slowly

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've a horizontal UIScrollview that shows around 10 images.
I know that we've to use scrollRectToVisible method to move the scrollview programmatically.
But what I am looking for is to scroll the scroll view slowly (5 pixels in 1 second) from start to end of the scroll view.

I have seen some pages, but I didn't understand how to integrate following code in my code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:(abs(rMid-pMid)*0.3)];
scrollMid.contentOffset = CGPointMake(rMid*320, 0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `NSTimer` like

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{       
    if (scrollingTimer == nil)
    {
        scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.06)
                         target:self selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];        
    }
}

- (void) autoscrollTimerFired
{
    if (scrollPoint.y == 583) // at where you want to stop scroll
    {
        [scrollingTimer invalidate];
        scrollingTimer = nil;
    }
    scrollPoint = CGPointMake(scrollPoint.x, scrollPoint.y + 1);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
}
```

hope its help you...

Comment: I don't personally have any particular use for this, but I tested it and it works like a charm!

Comment: Hi, This code really works. But the scrolling is not smooth. Even after changing animated to YES, the scrolling is not smooth. How can I achieve that functionality?

Comment: scrolling is depended on interval time and increment of Y