# Auto Scroll UITextView in iOS..

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, avaudioplayer

Everybody
How to scroll UITextView automatic as per AVAudioPlayer playing..?
I have one audio playing file and relates some text.. So, I want to visible only that text which text played by AVAudioPlayer.. I have create one UITextView and also AVAudioPlayer. But, I want to combine both.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857975/iphone-how-can-i-programatically-scroll-uiscrollview-from-start-to-end-slowly/6858063#6858063) to know how to scroll text view automatically. you have to modify code according to the time of your audio file.